# SymmetricDS only synchronizes one way

Tags: java, spring-boot, symmetricds

### Synconization only works from client to-> server , doesn't matter what is configured

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Node Groups
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
insert into sym_node_group (node_group_id) values ('client');

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Node Group Links
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- server sends changes to client when client pulls from server
insert into sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action, is_reversible)
 values ('server', 'client', 'W', 1);

-- client sends changes to server when client pushes to server
insert into sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action, is_reversible)
 values ('client', 'server', 'P', 1);


------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Channels
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
insert into sym_channel
(channel_id, processing_order, max_batch_size, enabled, description)
values('XXX', 1, 100000, 1, 'Everything');
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routers
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    insert into sym_router
   (router_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,router_type,create_time,last_update_time)
    values('server_2_client', 'server', 'client', 'default',current_timestamp, current_timestamp);


insert into sym_router
(router_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,router_type,create_time,last_update_time)
values('client_2_server', 'client', 'server', 'default',current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Triggers
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
insert into SYM_TRIGGER (trigger_id, source_table_name,
          channel_id, last_update_time, create_time)
                  values ('client_2_server', '*', 'XXX', current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
insert into SYM_TRIGGER (trigger_id, source_table_name,
          channel_id, last_update_time, create_time)
                  values ('server_2_client', '*', 'XXX', current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- SYM_TRIGGER_ROUTER
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
insert into SYM_TRIGGER_ROUTER (trigger_id, router_id, initial_load_order, create_time, last_update_time)
values ('client_2_server', 'client_2_server', 100, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
insert into SYM_TRIGGER_ROUTER (trigger_id, router_id, initial_load_order, create_time, last_update_time)
values ('server_2_client', 'server_2_client', 200, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
```

Comment: Have you tried with is_reversible equals to 0?

Comment: I have a guess, but I don't know why, the triggers are not created for the server at all.
The client  creates all the trigger according to the:
insert into SYM_TRIGGER (trigger_id, source_table_name,
          channel_id, last_update_time, create_time)
                  values ('client_2_server', '*', 'XXX', current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
Config, but when the server starts it does not run the configs. 
Is it a way to make it refresh?
I have start.refresh.cache.job=true set to true.

Comment: Are there any triggers created on any tables in server’s db?

Comment: Yes for the sym tables only.

Comment: Is thete a way to  force the trigger creation? After inserting it into the servers database with a script is is not read. Is it somehow possible to detect that a condig has changed?

Comment: Make a dummy update on sym_trigger table just to see if it worked

Comment: I could find, there is a snycTriggers() call code, and it made the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my configuration was added after SymetricEngine started (it was inserted with Flyway to the DB)

I needed to trigger the syncronization manually.

```
ServerSymmetricEngine serverEngine = new ServerSymmetricEngine(new File(url.getPath()));
serverEngine.setDeploymentType("server");
serverEngine.setup();
serverEngine.start();
// Here was the script inserts by flyway
serverEngine.syncTriggers();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the insert into sym_node_group (unless you have a copy-paste error in your post):

```
insert into sym_node_group (node_group_id) values ('server');
```

Also, set is_reversible to 0 for the sym_node_group_link rows.  That is an experimental feature that you don't need.  To get two-way replication, you simply need a group link in each direction, which you already have.

Comment: The server was created by default, and it is there. The problem was that SymmetricDS started server was started. I added this configs what was not created.
And then it was not resynced. I needed to call the synctriggers() from code, and than it created the missing tables.